# Handle special characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html-parsing, special-characters

I have a web page with the following code snippet:

```
...
<td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="190px" class="ms-formlabel">
   <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
      <nobr>
         QA Groupe des papiers
         <span class="ms-formvalidation" title="Ce champ est obligatoire." > *</span>
      </nobr>
   </h3>
</td>
...
<td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="190px" class="ms-formlabel">
   <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
      <nobr>
         QA Description métier
         <span class="ms-formvalidation" title="Ce champ est obligatoire." > *</span>
      </nobr>
   </h3>
</td>
<td valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
...
```

I am developing a JavaScript which is supposed to hide the table rows containing the strings `QA Groupe des papiers` and `QA Description métier`.

This is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       $("h3.ms-standardheader:contains('QA Groupe des papiers')").closest("tr").hide();
       $("h3.ms-standardheader:contains('QA Description métier')").closest("tr").hide();
    });
</script>
```

The script is working fine for the first row, but not for the second. I know the problem is related to the special character `é` in the second script, but I don't know how to resolve the problem. Please help, thanks.

Comment: replace `é` with it's corresponding unicode code point `\uXXXX`

Comment: For me it works (jQuery 1.8.1 with Chrome browser).

Comment: @greengit, I've found out that `é` code is `\u00E9`. but the following line doesn't work: $("h3.ms-standardheader:contains('QA Description m\" + \u00E9 + "tier')").closest("tr").hide(); Could you help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probable explanation is that the character encoding of the JavaScript file has not been declared properly in HTTP headers. Probably the JavaScript file is interpreted as ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252 encoded but is actually UTF-8 encoded, or vice versa, which means that “é” isn’t what it should be. A simple way to check this out is `alert('é')`. Regarding encodings issues, check out the W3C page [Character encodings](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset.en.php).

Comment: Adding `$('head').append('<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />');` to the script solves the isse. Thanks Jukka!

Answer (score 1):

Unicode is a complex thing. The character set has two different was of writing characters such as *á*, *é* etc.

Replacing one of the `é` characters with the other might solve your problem. (You can [read more about this at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence).)

If you continue to have problems, also **check the encoding** using which the JavaScript file and the web page are encoded.

Both the web page and the JavaScript file should be UTF-8 encoded and communicate this to the browser. This means that the web page must have at least one of the following

- An HTTP header which specifies the character encoding; e.g. `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`
- A `meta` tag which specifies the encoding; `<meta charset=UTF-8>` (*HTML5*) or `<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content='text/html; charset=UTF-8>`
- A [Byte Order Mark](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/parsing.html#determining-the-character-encoding) ([not recommended](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark))

The JavaScript file can be indicated as UTF-8 using one or more of the following methods:

- Using the [`charset`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_charset.asp) attribute
- Using an HTTP header which specifies the character encoding; e.g. `Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8`

**Further reading:**

- [All About Unicode, UTF8 & Character Sets](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/06/all-about-unicode-utf8-character-sets/)
- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: Unicode in general (UTF-8 is just a transfer encoding for Unicode) has two ways of writing é, but in the code posted, both the (common) precomposed form is used throughout.